# How to override breadcrumbs defined by a module using a custom module?

Tags: hooks, breadcrumbs

Is it possible, using a module, to override a breadcrumd definition defined in another module's hook_node_view()?

- Module `property_bc` sets a custom breadcrumb for nodes of type `Property`.
- Module `property_bc_plus` wants to override that behaviour.

`property_bc` implementation of `hook_node_view` would be:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_node_view().
 */
function property_bc_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($node->type == 'property') {
    $breadcrumb = array();
    $breadcrumb[] = l(t('Home'), NULL);
    $breadcrumb[] = l(check_plain($node->name), "user/$node->uid");
    $breadcrumb[] = l(t('Properties'), "user/$node->uid/properties");
    drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different solution depending of your context.

- Change the module order by changing their weight: http://drupal.org/node/110238
- Use an other hook than is called later like hook_node_view_alter
- Add a flag in your node and test against it

First module

```
 <?php
 function property_bc_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
      if ($node->type == 'property') {
        $breadcrumb = array();
        $breadcrumb[] = l(t('Home'), NULL);
        $breadcrumb[] = l(check_plain($node->name), "user/$node->uid");
        $breadcrumb[] = l(t('Properties'), "user/$node->uid/properties");
        $node->custom_bredcrumb_is_set = TRUE;
        drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
      }
    }
```

In your other module

```
    <?php
    function property_bc_plus_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
      if ($node->type == 'property' && isset($node->custom_bredcrumb_is_set) && $node->custom_bredcrumb_is_set != TRUE) {
        $breadcrumb = array();
        $node->custom_bredcrumb_is_set = TRUE;
        drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
      }

}
```

Comment: You solution is great. Just a note here, I didn't modify the first module since this is what I wanted to avoid in the first place.